# Start remote X session on local tty

Tags: xorg, tty, remote-desktop

I have access to two Linux boxes, both running X servers. Let's call them A and B. I do not always have physical access to machine A, though I can always access it remotely and I have admin access to it. On machine B, I do not have admin access (and even if I did I wouldn't want to screw around with the X server on it or other things, since it's a shared machine), though I do always have physical access.

Furthermore, I greatly prefer the desktop and window managers I have installed on machine A. I would like to start an X session using the window manager and desktop manager from machine A on a free tty (say, tty8) on machine B.

I know how to start a second local X session on a free tty using `startx -- :1`, so I tried `startx ssh B "gdm" -- :1` from machine B, but this failed with the error: `xterm: bad command line option "xterm"`. In fact, I got the same error regardless of the desktop manager that I tried to start on the remote machine.

I do not care whether I use a local X server or remote - I just want my desktop manager and window manager from the remote machine. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't think you can use a remote desktop manager like that. The closest you can get to something like this is [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) but it's not quite the same.

Comment: The overhead of VNC is too high. I've run X applications over SSH before; that's not difficult at all. So I figure that running a whole display manager or window manager is just another X application, right? So shouldn't I be able to forward it over SSH?

Answer (score 3):

The `-query` argument to `X` will allow you to specify a remote [**XDMCP**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_%28program_type%29#X_Display_Manager_Control_Protocol) server to connect to. Be sure that the display manager on machine A has XDMCP enabled.